# server.close в node js

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');

var server = new http.Server(function(req, res) {    
    res.end("a");
}).listen(3000);

setTimeout(function() {
    server.close();
},2500);
```

Почему если сделать запрос странице то `setTimeout` не сработает, а если не сделать то сработает, почему так ?

Comment: Все срабатывает. Добавьте `console.log` в  `setTimeout`

Comment: @Дмытрык, потыкайте f5 - пока не закрыто соединение - "всё не срабатывает"

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout срабатывает всегда, а вот server.close() только в случае если нет активных соединений

Из документации по методу [`server.close()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback)

> Stops the server from accepting new connections and keeps existing
>   connections. This function is asynchronous, the server is finally
>   closed when all connections are ended and the server emits a 'close'
>   event. The optional callback will be called once the 'close' event
>   occurs. Unlike that event, it will be called with an Error as its only
>   argument if the server was not open when it was closed.

Следовательно, после запроса соединение еще некоторое время считается активным. Если после запроса долгое время не будет других, то сервер тоже закроется.

**qwabra**:

хочу добавить, по аналогии с этим ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554590/4794368, что `res.setHeader('Connection', 'close');` - решит "проблему".

```
var http = require('http');

var server = new http.Server(async function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'close');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write(`<h1>hw</h1.`);
    res.end('');
}).listen(3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Timeout')
    server.close(() => { console.log('server.close') });
}, 2500);
```